# How to embed a table in a page layout

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

I have a requirement that I need to put a table to the page layout. There are so many fields in the object and it feels cluttered when creating a new record. So the users requested that I put a table within the page layout. I thought I can use Lightning Web Component for this. But there are also other fields within the object that doesn't need to be added to the LWC component and will stay in the page layout. How can I achieve this? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Salesforce have not yet allow custom components in the dynamic form creation and editing of records. You would have to either provide everything yourself, make creation a two step process (create basic record first then enter all the data after in LWC) or wait until they do.

Comment: Thank you @PhilW. That's what I thought, too.